# bit-field and storage unit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a doubt on my compiler using a 32 bit compiler (GCC MinGW) on a 64 bit machine.
When I use this struct:

```
struct S 
{
    unsigned int a : 2; 
    unsigned int b : 3;
    unsigned int c : 4;
    _Bool d : 1;
} s;
```

`sizeof s` returns 8 so my compiler is using my machine word that's 8 byte (64 bit) for packing bit fields. Why if the compiler is 32 bit? In fact `sizeof(int)` give me 4.

Moreover if I declare my struct as:

```
struct S 
{
    char a; 
    char b;
    char c;
    _Bool d;;
} s;
```

`sizeof s` give me 4 so it is better to pack the structure in this way to save more space.
So often is said that using bit field with structure can save space... but I think this is not always so... Am I missing some information?

Comment: Interestingly on gcc 64-bit (linux) it is also 4 for your first example.

Comment: Just don't use bit-fields because there is never a reason to do so... problem solved.

Comment: alwys getting 4 for both structs (on linux 64bit like @FatalError) the only thing i could imagine is that your compiler doesn't manage to pack `unsigned int` and `_Bool` into one `int`. What if you make it `unsigned int d: 1` ?

Comment: @FatalError, You're right. I also tried on my other computer (a linux box, that's 64 bit) and it returns 4... what a mystery!

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt, if I make unsigned int d: 1 the size is 4!!! What's the problem with _Bool?

Comment: I don't really know and as i said it doesn't happen to me. I guess your compiler some how thinks these are too different types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitfields are largely implementation-defined or even unspecified.

My guess is that switching from `unsigned int` to `_Bool` made your compiler start a completely new bit-field.

Anyway, you are right with the final resolution:
If you want something reliable and/or portable, pack them yourself.

Here all the relevant parts from C99+amendments (n1570).

> #### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> [...]
>   5 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type. It is implementation-defined whether atomic types are permitted.
>   [...]
>   10 10 A bit-field is interpreted as having a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits.125) If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type `_Bool`, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored; a `_Bool`
>   bit-field has the semantics of a `_Bool`.
>   11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.
>   12 A bit-field declaration with no declarator, but only a colon and a width, indicates an unnamed bit-field.126) As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bitfield, if any, was placed.
>   [...]
>   15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>   [...]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. Even though the likely answer is that "bitfields are so poorly specified, nobody actually knows what they do, including the compiler"...

Comment: @Lundin: How is "largely implementation-defined or even unspecified" not an answer to the question? Your comment just paraphrases that... Anyway, reformulted a bit.

Comment: The question is why is the compiler allocating the bit-field in such a stupid way? Sure, the C standard allows the compiler to go nuts whenever it sees a bit-field, but why did it do so?

Comment: As I said, reformulated and made it more explicit, hope that meets the bar now.

Comment: "My guess is that switching from unsigned int to _Bool made your compiler start a completely new bit-field." : This is the VS behavior, mingw by default try to follow the visual studio behavior. If you disable this option with  -mno-ms-bitfields the size will be 4, like with a Linux gcc